# Java applet viewer gives a yellow triangle error on a selector

Tags: java

I made a simple Color Selector for drawing shapes, and whenever i run it and Click on the choice selector, it has a little Yellow triangle with an ! in it, is there a way to get rid of this?

Comment: < Standard warning about applets being an ancient dead technology that should be forgotten by everyone >

Comment: Sorry, it's something for my programming class, they're thinking of switching to japplets or whatever, but it'll take a but to change the curriculum.

Comment: Yeah, it's just unfortunate that you're taught things that you can never really use in real life.

Answer (score 1):

The triangle exists as a security feature to alert users that they are looking at an applet window, and not a window of the operating system or an installed application. There is no way to hide it.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/appletwarning-135102.html